# I know there are n leafs in the tree, How many possible trees?

Tags: tree

I know there are n leafs in the tree, How many possible trees?
The tree can be arbitrary branched (at least 2-branch).

Comment: We are talking a binary tree yes?

Comment: Is this homework? What are your thought on this so far? What have you read so far?

Comment: @NeilEssy why would you assume that? It says it can be arbitrarily branched...

Answer (score 4):

YOUR original premise:

- tree has n leafs
- tree is arbitrarily branched

Question: how many possible trees?

Answer: infinitely many.

Demonstration:

Base case:

```
1 leaf:  (leaf)<---(node)
         (leaf)<---(node)<---(node)
         (leaf)<---(node)<---(node)<----(node)
         // and so on
```

Incremental case:
n+1 leafs: Same as before but add n more leafs to the parent of a previous leaf

Comment: Maybe, I didn't explain clearly, the tree is at least 2-branch.

Comment: @WhatisThat does that mean every node has at least 2 children or that there exists at least one node with at least 2 children?

Comment: every node has at least two children

Answer (score -2):

There is definitely no infinity many trees as previous answer offered.

All combinatorial objects have finite structure and trees with limited number of leaves too.

"Demonstration" shows nothing about infinity. It simply shows that we have an increment in quantity of trees if n is incremented. But n is finite natural number. Summing of natural numbers gives natural number if count of sum members is natural number.
I think to answer this question we can try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function.
But I  don't use it every day and can't provide answer quickly.

Comment: I disagree. By demonstrating that there are infinitely many lists with 1 last element, you do prove that there are infinitely many trees, because every list is also a tree.

Comment: Oh, sorry. You are right. I thought question isn't so simple.

Comment: Maybe, I didn't explain clearly, the tree is at least 2-branch.